# JQuery: Select/Highlight text across multiple ranges

Tags: jquery, select, highlight

I am trying to select/highlight text (like what would happen if you click+drag your mouse across some text) across multiple ranges.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrate's what I'd like to do but am unable to
http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/2816/

I tried adding `SelectText("selectme2");` to the JQuery but then it deselects the first div.

I got this method from here
[Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse/4562565#4562565) but it only selects a single range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, somehow it works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome, maybe a browser compatibility issue..

**HTML -**

```
<div class="selectme">Some text to highlight</div>
<div> Don't select this </div>
<div class="selectme">Select this text too.</div>
<br>
<p>Click me!</p>
```

**Javascript-**

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var strongs = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
    var s = window.getSelection();
    if(s.rangeCount > 2) s.removeAllRanges();

    for(var i = 0; i < strongs.length; i++) {
         var range = document.createRange();
         range.selectNode(strongs[i]);
         s.addRange(range);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function() {
        myClass="selectme";
       SelectText(myClass);   
    });
});
```

And here is a live [**JSfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDa7v/22/)

Comment: this does exactly what I want but you are right, it doesn't work for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is still impossible in all of the major browsers except for firefox after digging around some more. Here's 1 source http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-January/030102.html

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

use **[highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)** simple

see **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/2822/)**

and use code

```
$('p').click(function() {
       $("div").highlight("highlight");

    });
```

Comment: i think he wants to use it for `copy` and your solution wouldn't help

Comment: Rituraj, thanks for the attempt but Michael is right, I'd like to use the highlighting/selecting to copy the text, not highlight it.